# How to sort array containing objects by those object keys

Tags: php

I have such an array that I need to be able to sort by keys ASC and DESC

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2323
            [regno] => 45101008785
            [regdate] => 1993-03-26
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2322
            [regno] => 49201003827
            [regdate] => 1992-04-08
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2318
            [regno] => 240100720
            [regdate] => 1992-10-01
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2317
            [regno] => 900100881
            [regdate] => 1992-12-28
        )
)
```

IE, if client sets GET parameters to *?sort_by=regno&type=asc*, I need to sort this via PHP to:

```
Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2318
            [regno] => 240100720
            [regdate] => 1992-10-01
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2317
            [regno] => 900100881
            [regdate] => 1992-12-28
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2323
            [regno] => 45101008785
            [regdate] => 1993-03-26
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2322
            [regno] => 49201003827
            [regdate] => 1992-04-08
        )
)
```

How is this done?

Comment: It is odd. Having 4k+ rep you should know how to search (or at least how to ask good question)

Comment: Or at least how to sort array of objects..

Comment: Sorry, I have a long week after me and not thinking clearly.

Comment: this has been asked at least thousand times!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tested this - but it should be close.

Have these two functions

```
function sorter($type, $key) 
{
    if ($type === 'asc')
    {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return strcmp($a->{$key}, $b->{$key});
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return strcmp($b->{$key}, $a->{$key});
        };
    }
}
```

Then in your code

```
usort($array, sorter($type, $sort_by));
```

[Example #4 on php.net should give you further help as well](https://www.php.net/usort)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$arr = 'your_array';

function my_custom_sort( $a, $b ) {
   $cond = trim( $_GET[ 'sort_by' ] );
   $type = trim( $_GET[ 'type' ] );

   if( !isset( $a->{$cond} ) || !isset( $b->{$cond} ) ) {
     return 0;
   }

   // asc or desc
   $return = array( -1, 1 );
   switch( $type ) {
      case 'asc':
           $return = array( -1, 1 );
      case 'desc':
           $return = array( 1, -1 );
   }

   if( $a->{$cond} == $b->{$cond} ) {
      return 0;
   }

   return ($a->{$cond} < $b->{$cond}) ? $return[0] : $return[1];
}

usort( $arr, 'my_custom_sort' );
```